# Passing pdf form field to node.js/ electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, electron

Im developing an node.js/ electron app, that would take a pdf file, read filled form fields, and then save values as variables. Is that possible? I know that in Acrobat java script there is

```
this.getField
```

Is there a possibility to import a pdf document to my app, and then read it's fields?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [pdfform.js](https://github.com/phihag/pdfform.js) will be helpful here?

The documentation says:

> `list_fields` function which allows you to list all available fields and their types.

Perhaps it will also list the already-filled-in values? I have not used the library.